# Are there any problems with UpperCamelCase / lowerCamelCase in db schema?

Tags: sql, postgresql, naming-conventions

1. Will I bump into any issues if I use PascalCase for table names and lowerCamelCase for column names in my PostgreSQL database? Other than being forced to use quotes for such names. For example: `SELECT "User.normalizedEmail" FROM "User" WHERE "User.id" = 123`
2. What would be the matching convention for naming indexes and constraints then? `PK_User_id`/`UK_User_email`, or maybe `User_pkey`/`User_email_unq`..

Answer (score 0):

1. When you create a table `fOoBaR` you can stil use `foobar`/`FOOBAR`/`FoObAr`/`"foobar"` (unquoted names are stored in lowercase). You're only forced to use double quoted names when that name is a restricted keyword or contains non-allowed characters. And this is usually considered bad practice.

   For me case-sensitive object names are the most stupid thing in Standard SQL.
2. Whatever you choose, just use it consistently.

Comment: "Foobar," or "Barf, ew!"... ?